# Does making a derived C++ class "final" change the ABI?

Tags: c++, c++11, virtual-functions, abi, vtable

I'm curious if marking an existing derived C++ class as `final` to allow for de-virtualisation optimisations will change ABI when using C++11. My expectation is that it should have no effect as I see this as primarily a hint to the compiler about how it can optimise virtual functions and as such I can't see any way it would change the size of the struct or the vtable, but perhaps I'm missing something?

I'm aware this changes API here so that code that further derives from this derived class will no longer work, but I'm only concerned about ABI in this particular case.

Comment: Hardly normative, but GCC seems to make full use of that [hint](https://godbolt.org/z/dCB-qG). I don't think it affects the ABI. Calls via base class pointers or references must still work.

Comment: The ABI is not part of the C++ standard, so this will be implementation-defined (or implementation un-defined).  Still a valid question to ask what compilers do in practice, and I would imagine with so many other things being able to affect it (e.g. changing something from public to private), this would likely affect it too.

Comment: Provided you have `struct A { virtual void f(); }; struct B : A { void f() final; }; struct C : B {};` and a `B& b` i suppose the compiler could devirtualize `b.f()`.

Comment: For the [itanium C++ abi](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/cxxabi-1.83.html), there is a set of virtual table for each possible most derived object: vtable for A, vtable for A in B, etc... So the compiler does always know what is the final overrider for all vtable it generates. So the final keyword does not change this.

Comment: @Oliv sounds like an answer?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour In my mind it is closer to a speculation. I do not have a good grasp of the subject.

Comment: @Oliv "_For the itanium C++ abi,_ (...)" And probably for all existing C++ implementations. And for all possible C++ implementations that use vtables.

Comment: Are you interested in reasonable, plausible code or any legal code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Final on a function declaration `X::f()` implies that the declaration cannot be overridden, so all calls that name that declaration can be bound early (not those calls that name a declaration in a base class): if a virtual function is *final in the ABI*, the produced vtables can be incompatible with the one produced almost same class without final: calls to virtual functions that name declarations marked final can be assumed to be direct: trying to use a vtable entry (that should exist in the final-less ABI) is illegal.

The compiler could use the final guarantee to cut on the size of vtables (that can sometime grow a lot) by not adding a new entry that would be usually be added and that must be according to the ABI for non final declaration.

Entries are added for a declaration overriding a function not a (inherently, always) primary base or for a non trivially covariant return type (a return type covariant on a non primary base).

## Inherently primary base class: the simplest case of polymorphic inheritance

The simple case of polymorphic inheritance, a derived class inheriting non virtually from a single polymorphic base class, is the typical case of an always primary base: the polymorphic base subobject is at the beginning, the address of derived object is the same as the address of the base subobject, virtual calls can be made directly with a pointer to either, everything is simple.

These properties are true whether the derived class is a complete object (one that isn't a subobject), a most derived object, or a base class. (They are class invariants guaranteed at the ABI level for pointers of unknown origin.)

Considering the case where the return type isn't covariant; or:

### Trivial covariance

An example: the case where it's covariant with the same type as `*this`; as in:

```
struct B { virtual B *f(); };
struct D : B { virtual D *f(); }; // trivial covariance
```

Here `B` is inherently, invariably the primary in `D`: in all `D` (sub)objects ever created, a `B` resides at the same address: the `D*` to `B*` conversion is trivial so the covariance is also trivial: it's a static typing issue.

Whenever this is the case (trivial up-cast), covariance disappears at the code generation level.

Conclusion

In these cases the type of the declaration of the overriding function is trivially different from the type of the base:

- all parameters are almost the same (with only a trivial difference on the type of `this`)
- the return type is almost the same (with only a possible difference on the type of a returned pointer(*) type)

(*) since returning a reference is exactly the same as returning a pointer at the ABI level, references aren't discussed specifically

So no vtable entry is added for the derived declaration.

(So making the class final wouldn't be vtable simplification.)

## Never primary base

Obviously a class can only have one subobject, containing a specific scalar data member (like the vptr (*)), at offset 0. Other base classes with scalar data members will be at a non trivial offset, requiring non trivial derived to base conversions of pointers. So multiple interesting(**) inheritance will create non primary bases.

(*) The vptr isn't a normal data member at the user level; but in the generated code, it's pretty much a normal scalar data member known to the compiler.
(**) The layout of non polymorphic bases isn't interesting here: for the purpose of vtable ABI, a non polymorphic base is treated like a member subobject, as it doesn't affect the vtables in any way.

The conceptually simplest interesting example of a non primary, and non trivial pointer conversion is:

```
struct B1 { virtual void f(); };
struct B2 { virtual void f(); };
struct D : B1, B2 { };
```

Each base has its own vptr scalar member, and these vptr have different purposes:

- `B1::vptr` points to a `B1_vtable` structure
- `B2::vptr` points to a `B2_vtable` structure

and these have identical layout (because the class definitions are superposable, the ABI must generate superposable layouts); and they are strictly incompatible because

1. The vtables have distinct entries:

   - `B1_vtable.f_ptr` points to the final overrider for `B1::f()`
   - `B2_vtable.f_ptr` points to the final overrider for `B2::f()`
2. `B1_vtable.f_ptr` must be at the same offset as `B2_vtable.f_ptr` (from their respective vptr data members in `B1` and `B2`)
3. The final overriders of `B1::f()` and `B2::f()` aren't inherently (always, invariably) equivalent(*): they can have distinct final overriders that do different things.(***)

(*) Two callable runtime functions(**) are equivalent if they have same observable behavior at the ABI level. (Equivalent callable functions may not have the same declaration or C++ types.)

(**) A callable runtime function is any entry point: any address that can be called/jumped at; it can be a normal function code, a thunk/trampoline, a particular entry in a multiple entry function. Callable runtime functions often have no possible C++ declarations, like "final overrider called with a base class pointer".

(***) That they sometimes have the same final overrider in a further derived class:

```
struct DD : D { void f(); }
```

isn't useful for the purpose of defining the ABI of `D`.

So we see that `D` *provably* needs a non primary polymorphic base; by convention it will be `D2`; the first nominated polymorphic base (`B1`) gets to be primary.

So `B2` must be at non trivial offset, and `D` to `B2` conversion is non trivial: it requires generated code.

So the parameters of a member function of `D` cannot be equivalent with the parameters of a member function of `B2`, as the implicit `this` isn't trivially convertible; so:

- `D` must have two different vtables: a vtable corresponding with `B1_vtable` and one with `B2_vtable` (they are in practice put together in one big vtable for `D` but conceptually they are two distinct structures).
- the vtable entry of a virtual member of `B2::g` that is overridden in `D` needs two entries, one in the `D_B2_vtable` (which is just a `B2_vtable` layout with different values) and one in the `D_B1_vtable` which is an enhanced `B1_vtable`: a `B1_vtable` plus entries for new runtime features of `D`.

Because the `D_B1_vtable` is built from a `B1_vtable`, a pointer to `D_B1_vtable` is trivially a pointer to a `B1_vtable`, and the vptr value is the same.

Note that in theory is would be possible to omit the entry for `D::g()` in `D_B1_vtable` if the burden of making all virtual calls of `D::g()` via the `B2` base, which as far as no non trivial covariance is used(#), is also a possibility.

(#) or if non trivial covariance occurs, "virtual covariance" (covariance in a derived to base relation involving virtual inheritance) isn't used

## Not inherently primary base

Regular (non virtual) inheritance is simple like membership:

- a non virtual base subobject is a direct base of exactly one object (which implies that there always exactly one final overrider of any virtual function when virtual inheritance isn't used);
- the placement of a non virtual base is fixed;
- base subobject that don't have virtual base subobjects, just like data member, are constructed exactly like complete objects (they have exactly one runtime constructor function code for every defined C++ constructor).

A more subtle case of inheritance is virtual inheritance: a virtual base subobject can be the direct base of many base class subobjects. That implies that the layout of virtual bases is only determined at the most derived class level: the offset of a virtual base in a most derived object is well known and a compile time constant; in a arbitrary derived class object (that may or may not be a most derived object) it is a value computed at runtime.

That offset can never be known because C++ supports both unifying and duplicating inheritance:

- virtual inheritance is unifying: all virtual bases of a given type in a most derived object are one and the same subobject;
- non virtual inheritance is duplicating: all indirect non virtual bases are semantically distinct, as their virtual members don't need to have common final overriders (contrast with Java where this is impossible (AFAIK)):

  struct B { virtual void f(); };
  struct D1 : B { virtual void f(); }; // final overrider 
  struct D2 : B { virtual void f(); }; // final overrider 
  struct DD : D1, D2 { };

Here `DD` has **two** distinct final overriders of `B::f()`:

- `DD::D1::f()` is final overrider for `DD::D1::B::f()`
- `DD::D2::f()` is final overrider for `DD::D2::B::f()`

in two distinct vtable entries.

*Duplicating inheritance*, where you indirectly derive multiple times from a given class, implies multiple vptrs, vtables and possibly distinct vtable ultimate code (the ultimate aim of using a vtable entry: the high level semantic of calling a virtual function - not the entry point).

Not only C++ supports both, but the fact combinations are allowed: duplicating inheritance of a class that uses unifying inheritance:

```
struct VB { virtual void f(); };
struct D : virtual VB { virtual void g(); int dummy; };
struct DD1 : D { void g(); };
struct DD2 : D { void g(); };
struct DDD : DD1, DD2 { };
```

There is only one `DDD::VB` but there are two observably distinct `D` subobjects in `DDD` with different final overriders for `D::g()`. Whether or not a C++-like language (that supports virtual and non virtual inheritance semantic) guarantees that distinct subobjects have different addresses, the address of `DDD::DD1::D` cannot be at the same as the address of `DDD::DD2::D`.

So the offset of a `VB` in a `D` cannot be fixed (in any language that supports unification and duplication of bases).

In that particular example a real `VB` object (the object at runtime) has no concrete data member except the vptr, and the vptr is a special scalar member as it is a type "invariant" (not const) shared member: it is fixed on the constructor (invariant after complete construction) and its semantic is shared between bases and derived classes. Because `VB` has no scalar member that isn't type invariant, that in a `DDD` the `VB` subobject can be an overlay over `DDD::DD1::D`, as long as the vtable of `D` is a match for the vtable of `VB`.

This however cannot be the case for virtual bases that have non invariant scalar members, that is regular data members with an identity, that is members occupying a distinct range of bytes: these "real" data members cannot be overlayed on anything else. So a virtual base subobject with data members (members with with an address guaranteed to be distinct by C++ or any other the distinct C++-like language you are implementing) must be put at a distinct location: virtual bases with data members normally(##) have inherently non trivial offsets.

(##) with potentially a very narrow special case with a derived class with no data member with a virtual base with some data members

So we see that "almost empty" classes (classes with no data member but with a vptr) are special cases when used as virtual base classes: these virtual base are candidate for overlaying on derived classes, they are potential primaries but not inherent primaries:

- the offset at which they reside will only be determined in the most derived class;
- the offset might or might not be zero;
- a nul offset implies overlaying of the base, so the vtable of each directly derived class must be a match for the vtable of the base;
- a non nul offset implies non trivial conversions, so the entries in the vtables must treat conversion of the pointers to the virtual base as needing a runtime conversion (except when overlaid obviously as it wouldn't be necessary not possible).

This means that when overriding a virtual function in a virtual base, an adjustment is always assumed to be potentially needed, but in some cases no adjustment will be needed.

A *morally virtual base* is a base class relationship that involves a virtual inheritance (possibly plus non virtual inheritance). Performing a derived to base conversion, specifically converting a pointer `d` to derived `D`, to base `B`, a conversion to...

- ...a non-morally virtual base is inherently reversible in every case:

  - there is a one to one relation between the identity of a subobject `B` of a `D` and a `D` (which might be a subobject itself);
  - the reverse operation can be performed with a `static_cast<D*>`: `static_cast<D*>((B*)d)` is `d`;
- (in any C++ like language with complete support for unifying and duplicating inheritance) ...a morally virtual base is inherently non reversible *in the general case* (although it's reversible in common case with simple hierarchies). Note that:

  - `static_cast<D*>((B*)d)` is ill formed;
  - `dynamic_cast<D*>((B*)d)` will work for the simple cases.

So let's called *virtual covariance* the case where the covariance of the return type is based on morally virtual base. When overriding with virtual covariance, the calling convention cannot assume the base will be at a known offset. So a **new vtable entry** is inherently needed for virtual covariance, whether or not the overridden declaration is in an inherent primary:

```
struct VB { virtual void f(); }; // almost empty
struct D : virtual VB { }; // VB is potential primary

struct Ba { virtual VB * g(); };
struct Da : Ba { // non virtual base, so Ba is inherent primary
  D * g(); // virtually covariant: D->VB is morally virtual
};
```

Here `VB` may be at offset zero in `D` and no adjustment may be needed (for example for a complete object of type `D`), but it isn't always the case in a `D` subobject: when dealing with pointers to `D`, one cannot know whether that is the case.

When `Da::g()` overrides `Ba::g()` with virtual covariance, the general case must be assumed so a **new vtable entry** is strictly needed for `Da::g()` as there is no possible down pointer conversion from `VB` to `D` that reverses the `D` to `VB` pointer conversion in the general case.

`Ba` is an inherent primary in `Da` so the semantics of `Ba::vptr` are shared/enhanced:

- there are additional guarantees/invariants on that scalar member, and the vtable is extended;
- no new vptr is needed for `Da`.

So the `Da_vtable` (inherently compatible with `Ba_vtable`) needs two distinct entries for virtual calls to `g()`:

- in the `Ba_vtable` part of the vtable: `Ba::g()` vtable entry: calls final overrider of `Ba::g()` with an implicit this parameter of `Ba*` and returns a `VB*` value.
- in the new members part of the vtable: `Da::g()` vtable entry: calls final overrider of `Da::g()` (which by is inherently the same as final overrider of `Ba::g()` in C++) with an implicit this parameter of `Da*` and returns a `D*` value.

Note that there is not really any ABI freedom here: the fundamentals of vptr/vtable design and their intrinsic properties imply the presence of these multiple entries for what is a unique virtual function at the high language level.

Note that making the virtual function body inline and a visible by the ABI (so that the ABI by classes with different inline function definitions could be made incompatible, allowing more information to inform memory layout) wouldn't possibly help, as inline code would only define what a call to a non overridden virtual function does: one cannot based the ABI decisions on choices that can be overridden in derived classes.

[Example of a virtual covariance that ends up being only trivially covariant as in a complete `D` the offset for `VB` is trivial and no adjustment code would have been necessary in that case:

```
struct Da : Ba { // non virtual base, so inherent primary
  D * g() { return new D; } // VB really is primary in complete D
                            // so conversion to VB* is trivial here
};
```

Note that in that code an incorrect code generation for a virtual call by a buggy compiler that would use the `Ba_vtable` entry to call `g()` would actually work because covariance ends up being trivial, as `VB` is primary in complete `D`.

The calling convention is for the general case and such code generation would fail with code that returns an object of a different class.

--end example]

But if `Da::g()` is final in the ABI, only virtual calls can be made via the `VB * g();` declaration: covariance is made purely static, the derived to base conversion is be done at compile time as the last step of the virtual thunk, as if virtual covariance was never used.

## Possible extension of final

There are two types of virtual-ness in C++: member functions (matched by function signature) and inheritance (match by class name). If final stops overriding a virtual function, could it be applied to base classes in a C++-like language?

First we need to define what is overriding a virtual base inheritance:

An "almost direct" subobject relation means that a indirect subobject is controlled almost as a direct subobject:

- an almost direct subobject can be initialized like a direct subobject;
- access control is never a really obstacle to access (inaccessible private almost direct subobjects can be made accessible at discretion).

Virtual inheritance provides almost direct access:

- constructor for each virtual bases must be called by ctor-init-list of the constructor of the most derived class;
- when a virtual base class is inaccessible because declared private in a base class, or publicly inherited in a private base class of a base class, the derived class has the discretion to declare the virtual base as a virtual base again, making it accessible.

A way to formalize virtual base overriding is to make an imaginary inheritance declaration in each derived class that overrides base class virtual inheritance declarations:

```
struct VB { virtual void f(); };
struct D : virtual VB { };
struct DD : D
  // , virtual VB  // imaginary overrider of D inheritance of VB
  {
  // DD () : VB() { } // implicit definition
};
```

Now C++ variants that support both forms of inheritance don't have to have C++ semantic of almost direct access in all derived classes:

```
struct VB { virtual void f(); };
struct D : virtual VB { };
struct DD : D, virtual final VB {
  // DD () : VB() { } // implicit definition
};
```

Here the virtual-ness of the `VB` base is frozen and cannot be used in further derived classes; the virtual-ness is made invisible and inaccessible to derived classes and the location of `VB` is fixed.

```
struct DDD : DD {
  DD () : 
    VB() // error: not an almost direct subobject
  { } 
}; 
struct DD2 : D, virtual final VB {
  // DD2 () : VB() { } // implicit definition
}; 
struct Diamond : DD, DD2 // error: no unique final overrider
{                        // for ": virtual VB"
};
```

The virtual-ness freeze makes it illegal to unify `Diamond::DD::VB` and `Diamond::DD2::VB` but virtual-ness of `VB` requires unification which makes `Diamond` a contradictory, illegal class definition: no class can ever derive from both `DD` and `DD2` [analog/example: just like no useful class can directly derive from `A1` and `A2`:

```
struct A1 {
  virtual int f() = 0;
};
struct A2 {
  virtual unsigned f() = 0;
};
struct UselessAbstract : A1, A2 {
  // no possible declaration of f() here
  // none of the inherited virtual functions can be overridden
  // in UselessAbstract or any derived class
};
```

Here `UselessAbstract` is abstract and no derived class are too, making that ABC (abstract base class) extremely silly, as any pointer to `UselessAbstract` is provably a null pointer.

-- end analog/example]

That would provide a way to freeze virtual inheritance, to provide meaningful private inheritance of classes with virtual base (without it derived classes can usurp the relationship between a class and its private base class).

Such use of final would of course freeze the location of a virtual base in a derived class and its further derived classes, avoiding additional vtable entries that are only needed because the location of virtual base isn't fixed.

Comment: Could you make a tl;dr for this?

Comment: @MarkRansom In theory final allows vtable to be shorter in a few special cases, so ABI incompatibility is conceivable.

Comment: I didn't even consider the cases of obviously useless virtualness, like declaring a new virtual final function or new virtual final inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that adding the `final` keyword should not be ABI breaking, however removing it from an existing class might render some optimizations invalid. For example, consider this:

```
// in car.h
struct Vehicle { virtual void honk() { } };
struct Car final : Vehicle { void honk() override { } };

// in car.cpp

// Here, the compiler can assume that no derived class of Car can be passed,
// and so `honk()` can be devirtualized. However, if Car is not final
// anymore, this optimization is invalid.
void foo(Car* car) { car->honk(); }
```

If `foo` is compiled separately and e.g. shipped in a shared library, removing `final` (and hence making it possible for users to derive from `Car`) could render the optimization invalid.

I'm not 100% sure about this though, some of it is speculation.

Comment: Wouldn't removing `final` violate the ODR? At that point you'd get undefined behavior.

Comment: Why would it be a violation of the ODR?

Comment: You can't have two conflicting definitions of the same object. Your example is exactly why it isn't allowed. You're talking about compiling twice, once with an old definition and once with a new definition.

Comment: Well.. that's almost always what we do, right? We compile a .so against one set of headers and ship it to users. They build applications using those headers and they link to the .so. Then we change the headers (in ways we believe not to be ABI-breaking), we recompile the .so, and we ship it again, and we expect their application to still work.

With your interpretation, _any_ change to the definition of the class is an ODR-violation. FWIW, the standard library adds things like private member functions to classes all the time.

With your interpretation, the answer to this question is "yes".

Comment: The standard library expects you to recompile everything when you get a new set of headers. Especially if new private members were added you'd get a different object size, and it's critical for the compiler to know that.

Comment: The size of the class doesn't change when you add private member functions.

The Standard Library does not expect you to recompile everything when you get a new set of headers because that would be a completely unreasonable requirement. Most people can't recompile everything, for example if they ship binaries to users. Source: I maintain libc++ and we don't expect people to recompile. It's called ABI compatibility and we try hard not to break it.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood - I took "private members" to be variables, not functions. Is ABI compatibility in that case guaranteed by the standard, or do you have to rely on guarantees by a specific compiler? I'm guessing it's the latter, even if it's not a hard guarantee to make.

Comment: ABI compatibility is something that vendors are free to guarantee (or not). It's very hard to guarantee, by the way, and it highly restricts what kind of changes we can make in the library. I don't know of many libraries with a C++ interface that provide ABI stability beyond the standard library.

The Standard does not specify anything related to the ABI. However, vendors that care about ABI stability make sure that we do not standardize changes that would require ABI breaks to be implemented.. although sometimes stuff slips and we have a bad day.

Comment: @LouisDionne Stability of a library interface is easy to guarantee via a systematic practices of using indirections (like stdio).

Comment: @MarkRansom Even in C there are quite often different calling convention at least for things that go beyond a function returning a scalar.

Comment: Louis and Mark are both right :-) adding or removing `final` _does_ change the class definition, and so strictly speaking _does_ require recompiling all code that uses it, otherwise you get an ODR violation, and so UB. In practice, the outcome of such an ODR violation will be that previously-compiled code that saw the `final` version of the class might have devirtualized some calls and so would not dynamically dispatch to an overriding function in a derived class. That's arguably a "relatively" "harmless" form of UB. The solution to fix it would be to recompile the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not introduce new virtual methods in your `final` class (only override methods of parent class) you should be ok (the virtual table is going to be the same as the parent object, because it must be able to be called with a pointer to parent), if you introduce virtual methods the compiler can indeed ignore the `virtual` specifier and only generate standard methods, e.g:

```
class A {
    virtual void f();
};

class B final : public A {
    virtual void f(); // <- should be ok
    virtual void g(); // <- not ok
};
```

The idea is that every time in C++ that you can invoke the method `g()` you have a pointer/reference whose static and dynamic type is `B`: static because the method does not exist except for `B` and his children, dynamic because `final` ensures that `B` has no children. For this reason you never need to do virtual dispatch to call the *right* `g()` implementation (because there can be only one), and the compiler might (and should) not add it to the virtual table for `B` - while it is forced to do so if the method could be overridden. This is basically the whole point for which the `final` keyword exist as far as I understand

Comment: please note that even the case where the function exists already does not give you any guarantee that the ABI won't change, although it is reasonable it won't, because how each compiler implements `virtual` is not specified.

Comment: @curiousguy yeh I do like the father/children methaphor, and wasn't going for a formal and complete answer because there is already one here and it's pretty good

Comment: @curiousguy yes it is. Basically I expect the virtual table for `B` that express the `A` interface to be fine, not so much for the `B` interface if it is different from `A`

Comment: OK then I'm deleting my previous comments to reduce the clutter.

Comment: @curiousguy That is the point. He may rely on them being present in the virtual method table to invoke them in some other method (e.g., COM) because he wrote `virtual` but the compiler might outsmart him and optimize that away (because he knows it's `final`)

Comment: "_present in the virtual method table to invoke them in some other method_" I get it now. Maybe you could add the description of intent in the answer.